# node.js and socket.io code not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am using this code for simple broadcasting things.

server side

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );

var io = socket.listen( server );

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
console.log( "New client !" );

client.on( 'message', function( data ) {
    console.log( 'Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message );

    client.broadcast.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
    client.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
});
});

server.listen( 16558 );
```

and for the client side I am using this code to send and receive messages from other users who are online
Clientside

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:16558' );

$( "#messageForm" ).submit( function() {
var nameVal = $( "#nameInput" ).val();
var msg = $( "#messageInput" ).val();

socket.emit( 'message', { name: nameVal, message: msg } );

// Ajax call for saving datas
$.ajax({
    url: "./ajax/insertNewMessage.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { name: nameVal, message: msg },
    success: function(data) {

    }
});

return false;
});

socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
    var actualContent = $( "#messages" ).html();
var newMsgContent = '<li> <strong>' + data.name + '</strong> : ' + data.message + '</li>';
var content = newMsgContent + actualContent;

$( "#messages" ).html( content );
});
```

when new client is added "New client" is displayed on console but when any user send message it is not displayed on console

I am not getting error but the messages are not broadcasted.
Can any one help me regarding this.
Any other things that can help me.

Comment: 'message' is a reserved event name so try to use other names as suggested below in answer

Comment: when new client is added "New client" is displayed on console but when any user message it is not displayed on console

Comment: I have changed event name but still it is not working

Comment: It means the error is on your client code, because 'message' event is not being triggered

Comment: can you suggest anything what can be error on client side

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the following is false!!!

<strike>Try calling your event something other than 'message'. The on('message') handler will only be called on a socket.send() from the other side. If you want your socket.emit() to work you need to use a nonreserved event name.</strike>

Ref: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events

Comment: on changing event name from message to msg, it is not working

Comment: I actually tested it and it turns out that emit('message') will trigger on('message') just fine. I tried out your code (at least the socket.io parts) and it seems to work as intended, don't know what might be going wrong. Are you sure the socket.emit('message') is being called on the client side?

Comment: is there any other method to send message from client side

Comment: I am not sure weather emit is working fine on client side as I am not getting any data on server side, can you suggest any other thing other socket method or event

Answer (score 0):

You dont nee ajax to dispaly things. And to emit things, use the io.emit. It emits to all the users. And change client code to:

```
socket.on('message', function(data){
   $('#messages').append('<b>'+ data.name + '</b>:<b>' + data.message + '</b>');
```

Comment: If you want , i can send you a code that displays new user whenever he connects.